# Closing a SqlDataReader and locks aquired by sp_getapplock

Tags: sqldatareader, locks

Here's my process flow:

1. Create a database connection in a using clause
2. Call sp_getapplock
3. Create a SqlDataReader to get data
4. Either call reader.Close() or wrap SqlDataReader in using clause.
5. Call sp_releaseapplock
6. Close db using clause.

When I execute step 5, an exception is thrown because I no longer hold the lock.

Can I safely omit the call to sp_releaseapplock and rely on the closing of the SqlDataReader to release and clean up that lock?

Comment: You might want to tag this question as a SQL Server question and indicate that in the text of the question itself, since I believe this is specific to SQL Server and possibly Transact SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This had to do with the way the SqlDataReader was executed.  Buried a little deeper in code the ExecuteReader was being called with CommanBehavior.Connection.